# Latex templates for project management tasks

Tags: templates

Where can I find latex templates for project management tasks like work-breakdown structure doc, CPM/PERT diagrams, final project reports etc ?

Examples here:
[link1](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0NJuNGnNU9yNWRiNmIxMjctNzBmNi00ZTEzLWJlN2EtMGFkYWRmODZhZjU5&hl=en&authkey=CMzarrgH)
[link2](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0NJuNGnNU9yNjViMjNhZjQtMGVlNi00YWM2LWE2NTEtZTRiYTk1MjQ4NmZj&hl=en&authkey=CL-Uz_oO)
[link3](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0NJuNGnNU9yMzZlNjFhZDItZmZlOC00NTQ0LTkxMDItZmNjYjkxYmQ2NmVm&hl=en&authkey=CL-KmpYC)
[link4](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0NJuNGnNU9yYjY1NDAzNTktOWU3OS00OTAzLTkwNDgtZTk3ODA4ZjA1MDE3&hl=en&authkey=CLKUx6MJ)
[link5](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0NJuNGnNU9yZjE2OWVmZWEtOTUzZi00NzM5LWFkZTYtYTdkMmJlOTI4ZDk0&hl=en&authkey=CPWKvqoG)

Answer (score 9):

Recently a package (based on tikz) for [gantt charts](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php) has been published

Answer (score 5):

Is [this](http://jldiaz.wikidot.com/en-tikz-example%3agantt) something of interest to you? It uses tikz/pgf.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`pgfgantt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) package shipped with MiKTeX and TeXLive.

I have tried it using the example code in the manual it produces the desired effect but has lots output errors even though I have the latest version of pgf (as mentioned in manual).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5cm, y=1cm]
\begin{ganttchart}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
\ganttlink[b-m]{7}{5}{7}{6}
\ganttlink[m-b]{7}{6}{8}{7}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: @seamus Thanks for the tips. I was thinking my original post was a bit blocky...

Answer (score 0):

There is also [pst-gantt](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-gantt/), which is based on pstricks. It is a bit older and more clunky though.